# How to ensure file exists in Django project?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-models

My question is simple as the title clearly describes it.

I have `FileField` in some models, I added a property method to check the existence of file:

```
@property
def file_exists(self):
    # Because sometimes, the field may contain the string path
    # but the file doesn't exist at all in the server
    if file: # if the string path exists
        return os.path.exists(self.file.path) # If the file exists in server
```

This works perfectly in development, but when I migrate all my files on AWS, it raises an Error such I don't have permission to do that.

I wonder what's wrong, or Is there another way to test whether a file exists?

Comment: did you test with `with open(file.path):` if the file doesn't exist, it will raise an Exception?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should use the storage-agnostic [`Storage.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.exists) method.

The storage object should be available on the `FieldFile` itself, so something like

```
return self.file.storage.exists(self.file.name)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Wow! that's what I was looking for. if I could up-vote twice, I would do. thanks

Comment: Naaah. Be carefull, if file is None, e.g. it is not picked. This solution will give you True. Cause `file.storage.exists("") is True`

Answer (score 4):

It is also **important/safer/faster** to check for **file name** is not None before [Storage.exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.exists) method.

```
def is_file_exists(file_obj):
    return bool(file_obj.name) and file_obj.storage.exists(file_obj.name)
```

Comment: Can you pls explain, why Django storage.exists return True on empty filename?

Comment: @Богдан Соловьев look into source. It joins storage folder with file path and tries to check existence of storage folder! Sooo lame =)

Comment: @rappongy yep, already got it, after writes this comment)

Answer (score 2):

In Django 3+:

```
model.file_field.field.storage.exists(model.file_field.name)
```