# Do not save model on duplicate file - Django 2

Tags: python, django

I am trying to check for an existing file and overwriting it, so far I am able to do it using a custom storage, which looks something like this

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class DuplicateFileStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):

        return name

    def _save(self, name, content):
        if self.exists(name):
            self.delete(name)

        return super(DuplicateFileStorage, self)._save(name, content)
```

The above class checks for an existing file and deletes it.

And the model it looks after is:

```
class DataStorageModel(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='data_storage', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, help_text="File Name")
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=user_directory_path, storage=DuplicateFileStorage())
    relative_path = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, help_text="Relative Path if folder else null")

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):

        self.file.delete()

        return super(DataStorageModel, self).delete()
```

The problem is that though it removes and writes the same file it also creates a new model entry with the same existing path, that is if I upload the same file twice, I get one file in the OS path but two model entries. Something like this (there is an image here):

[image: screenshot]

So I tried using the `clean()` method with `self.file.storage.exists(self.file.name)` (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606068/how-to-ensure-file-exists-in-django-project)) but I get the existance as `False`, even though there is a file there.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):

    self.full_clean()

    return super(DataStorageModel, self).save()

def clean(self):

    print(self.file.storage.exists(self.file.name))  # <--- False
```

So my question is, how should I check if a duplicate file exists, overwrite the file but don't create a new record?

**Edit**

I forgot to put in the `user_director_path()`:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    """
    If relative path is not ``null`` the files will be stored as is else it will be
    stored to the root directory.
    """

    if instance.relative_path != 'null':
        return 'user_{0}{1}'.format(instance.user.id, instance.relative_path)
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)
```

I think I got it if I do this:

```
def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):

    if self.file.storage.exists('user_{0}{1}'.format(self.user.id, self.relative_path)):
        raise ValidationError('File already exists.')
```

It works but the whole upload fails, not even rewrite of files

Comment: did you try [**`update_or_create()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) ??]

Comment: Where should I be using that? In `clean` or `save()`, coz if I use it in save as `DataStorageModel.objects.update_or_create(user=self.user, file=self.file)` I am getting `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` if I use `self.objects.update_or_create(user=self.user, file=self.file)` I get manager cannot be reached.

Comment: You should provide `defaults` tooo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition, **`if instance.relative_path != 'null':`** is wrong. It should be just **`if instance.relative_path:`**
When I tried your snippet I felt something wrong with the **`user_directory_path`** function. So, I changed it to something like below.

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    """
    If relative path is not ``null`` the files will be stored as is else it will be
    stored to the root directory.

    The "relative_path" path should not be start or ends with a slash ("/") but, can use slash inside

    /foo/ -> Not allowed
    /foo/bar -> Not allowed
    foo/bar/ -> Not allowed

    foo -> Allowed
    foo/bar -> Allowed
    foo/bar/foobar -> Allowed

    """

    if instance.relative_path:
        relative_path = instance.relative_path
        if relative_path[0] == '/':
            relative_path = relative_path[1:]
        if relative_path[:-1] == '/':
            relative_path = relative_path[:-1]

        return 'user_{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.user.id, relative_path, filename)
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)
```

---

Now coming to our solution, I've created a sample view which will solve the issue.

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse


def foo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        create_data = {
            "user_id": request.user.pk,
            "file": request.FILES['file_name']
        }

        ds_temp = DataStorageModel(**create_data)
        path = user_directory_path(ds_temp, ds_temp.file.name)
        try:
            ds_existing = DataStorageModel.objects.get(file=path)
            ds_existing.file = create_data['file']
            ds_existing.save()
            return HttpResponse("instance modified")
        except DataStorageModel.DoesNotExist:
            ds_temp.save()
            return HttpResponse("new instance created")
    return HttpResponse("HTTP GET method")
```

Comment: True, I forgot that this should be done in the views rather than models. `user_directory_path` what you wrote creates a folder for every file, that is for - `temp.txt` it creates `temp.txt/temp.txt`

Comment: My logic is, if relative path exists, it will create sub directories under the user directory. If  relative path doesn't exists, the file will be saves to the user directory itself

Comment: Ya if I am uploading a folder, I get relative paths as `something/something-text.txt` and the file names separately, (I am using uppy.js)

Comment: Uploading **folder**? (folder or file?)

Comment: Both actually, if I upload a folder I get a relative path only to that folder if not I get relative paths as null.

Comment: Can you show that with the helo of few screenshots?